# PHP see a string such as single char

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have this code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
function ImportCSV2Array($filename)
{
    $row = 0;
    $col = 0;

    $handle = @fopen($filename, "r");
    if ($handle) 
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096,";")) !== false) 
        {
            if (empty($fields)) 
            {
                $fields = $row;
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($row as $k=>$value) 
            {
                $results[$col][$fields[$k]] = $value;
            }
            $col++;
            unset($row);
        }
        if (!feof($handle)) 
        {
            echo "Error: unexpected fgets() failn";
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return $results;
}
include_once("../config.php");
$nome_file = "./".$_GET['file'];

$csvArray = ImportCSV2Array($nome_file);
$i = 0;
foreach ($csvArray as $row=>$value)
{

$mp = array("1","2","3","4","5","7","11","12","13","16","17","18","26","27","28","33","34","42","43","45");
$fin = array("0","1","2","4","8","15","20","21","22","30","31","32","40","41","42","52","54","81","82","91");
            $codEvento = str_replace($mp, $fin, trim($value['CODEV']));

        if($value['INDEX']==0){
            echo $codEvento."-".$value['CODEV'].";".$value['COGNNOME'].";".$value['TEMPO'].";".$value['ANNO'].";".$value['DATA']."<br>";

        }
    }

?>
```

When I try to covert the $mp array in $fin array with str_replace, I have a problem.

If in the first time my $value['CODEV'] contains "12", it replace with 23 because the 1 is replaced by 2 and 2 by 3. Why it see "12" string such us two different strings? Why it doesn't replace "12" with "21"?

Comment: you're doing **STRING** replacements. `"12"` is a string, which means it's the CHARACTERS `1` and `2`, it's not "number twelve".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you supply an array as your search & replace parameters to `str_replace` it will loop through and replace each found search string with the corresponding replace string in your input.

In your case, "12" is the input, so the first action it takes is to replace the "1" with "0", leaving a value of "02".  Next it finds "2" and replaces it with "1" giving you a value of "01". There are no more matches so you will end up with "01".

If you re-ordered the search/replace pairs so that "12" shows up earlier in the list, you'd still get the wrong values. The first search would replace "12" with "21" (what you want), but later passes would replace the "1" with "0" and "2" with "1" leaving you with "10" this time.

The problem is that your array of search strings steps on itself. If the input string is to be entirely replaced, then perhaps a loop would be better, like this:

```
$mp = array("1","2","3","4","5","7","11","12","13","16","17","18","26","27","28","33","34","42","43","45");
$fin = array("0","1","2","4","8","15","20","21","22","30","31","32","40","41","42","52","54","81","82","91");
$input = "12";
$output = "?";
for ($i=0; $i<count($mp); $i++) {
    if ($input === $mp[$i]) {
        $output = $fin[$i];
        break;
    }
}
echo $output
```